# Generic list conversion to an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics

Assuming that I have the following class

```
public class A <T>{

    private T [] datas;
    // more code here ...
}
```

And I desire to take advantage of the constructor to initialize the array. Suppose that I have the following constructor

```
public A(T element){....}
```

Java does not allow me to use something like

```
datas = new T[10]
```

And it will complain that I **cannot create a generic array of T** 
But I can still use a work around like:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public A(T element){

       List<T> datasList = new ArrayList<T>();
       datasList.add(element);
       datas =(T[]) datasList.toArray();
    }
```

I have a warning from the compiler that's why I had to add the @SuppressWarnings, but my point is related to the following comment from the toArray method documentation (Please take a look at the picture)

[image]

*It talks about the returned array being safe*. **So does that means it is safe to use this method**? If not why? And  what would be a better way to do such an initialisation in a constructor? I would like to also consider the case of a variable list of T elements in an overloaded constructor like

public A(T... elements){....}.

Comment: You don't have to use a list but could try `(T[])Array.newInstance(element.getClass(), 10)`. This will still generate the warning due to the cast but you can safely ignore that as long as `element.getClass()` is `Class<T>` (which it should be in most cases - unless `T` is defined by something else and `element` would be a subclass of the defined `T`).

Comment: @Thomas thanks. that would do the trick.

Comment: Nice option, I didn't think of this. Upvoted the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of a generic array using the following:

```
public A(T element){
  int length = 10;
  datas  = (T[])Array.newInstance(element.getClass(), length);
}
```

However, there's a problem if `element` would be a subclass of `T`, e.g. if you'd call it like this:

```
A<Number> numberA = new A<>( Integer.valueOf(1) );
```

Here `T` would be `Number` but the class of `element` would be `Integer`.
To mitigate that you could pass a vararg array of type `T`, e.g. like this:

```
//firstElement only exists to force the caller to provide at least one element
//if you don't want this then just use the varargs array
A(T firstElement, T... furtherElements){      
  int length = 10;
  Class<?> elementClass = furtherElements.getClass().getComponentType();      
  datas  = (T[])Array.newInstance( elementClass, length);
}
```

Since varargs always result in an array (even of length 0) you'll get an array of type `T` and can get the component type of that.

So in the case above `numberA.datas` would be a `Number[]` array and not an `Integer[]` array.

Comment: Good point about the subclass, but in that case I would suggest adding "Class< T > clazz" instead of the T firstElement

Comment: @JeroenvanDijk yes that would be the safest way but would require a different api (which might be hard to change).

Comment: True (again) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass generics, but you can't call new `T (or new T[ ])`.
Keep in mind that generics are gone after compilation, so it actually only helps when writing the code. Knowing it's gone during runtime, it's also obvious that new T( ) can't be called as generic, T is removed in runtime.

It's safe to do, because you create that list in full control, accepting only objects of your generic type.

A nicer way (imho) is to create a static method as it is purely input-->output. You have to declare your generics before the method return type:

```
public < T > T[ ] toArray(T... objects) { ... }
```